# My OneDrive suddenly disappeared from my windows explorer in Windows 10. How do I turn it back?

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-onedrive

My OneDrive files and folders used to be seen in windows explorer, in Windows 10. But I can't see them right now. I have already restarted Windows a couple times, to no avail.

Comment: Go to https://onedrive.live.com/ and follow instructions from there for "get Apps" and so on.

Comment: Right click the OneDrive folder and select "pin to quick access". Does the folder C:/Users/<username>/OneDrive exist? Maybe you disabled OneDrive autostart in the task manager?

Comment: Have you checked that OneDrive is running and working? OneDrive is pretty hard to remove from File Explorer, even when you want to. Not that you tried removing it, but that it would mean something rather significant occurred to cause it to not be there.

Comment: @music2myear Thank you for your comment above. I had checked this out a couple of days ago, and you're right. I don't know why, but I was not signed in to OneDrive. Now everything seems to working as expected.